# Get button touch event type in custom class

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, touch-event

Is it possible to get the button touch event type (i.e. touchupinside, touchupoutside, touchdragdown etc.) in custom class.

```
 class MyButton : UIButton {
    override func sendAction(_ action: Selector, to target: Any?, for event:        
    UIEvent?) {
         debugPrint("Am here")

         /* below code is just for understanding what i want
         if event.type == touchupinside {
              //do something
         }
         else if event.type == touchdragdown {
              //do something else
         }
         */

         super.sendAction(action, to: target, for: event)
}
```

}

Comment: wouldn't it be better to add those event on the button and just forward it to a function? i.e. button.addTarget(<>,action:#selector(didTouchUpInside), for: .touchupInside),  button.addTarget(<>,action:#selector(didTouchupOutside), for: .touchUpOutside)

Comment: I don't want to add those method in every class for every button. I just want to make a custom class of UIButton and can set the subclass of UIButton on IB. Then it will get called all the time as there touch event type.

Comment: IMO, you can still do what you want but with a target/function call then add a callback to each respective method and your subclass just listen to the needed callback